# Override helptext in Wagtail EditView

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am trying to override the helptext that is set in my model in the wagtail admin (an edit view). I have tried the code below but the text is not changed, why is that?

```
    class MemberRegistrationEditView(EditView):

        def get_form(self):
            form = super().get_form()
            form.base_fields.get("own_email").help_text = "Test"
            return form
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` in `get_form` to see if this function is executed.

Comment: I have added a breakpoint to check, and it is hit.

Comment: you could use `print()` to check what you have in `.help_text` before assigning `Test`. Maybe it doesn't exist and you use wrong field.

Comment: @furas I have used breakpoints to check that it is actually overriding the correct field, but that does not reflect when the full page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your question. I understand what you're trying to achieve i think.
Generally speaking though, and others may disagree, but I would do this inside of the forms dunder init function (`__init__`)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_fields['own_email'].help_text = "Test"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Its worth noting that this will replace the help text for every time this particular form is used.

If you want to do something specific while in a certain view, then I would recommend simply inheriting the form you want instead of forms.Form and then replace the form attribute on the view for your new form.